# Insert random string

Tags: sql, oracle

У меня есть `table APP` и колонки `ID` и `pw`, Здесь у меня `ID auto increment` мне надо создать тригер, импорт делает очередной `ID` в колонке `pw` генерировал случайний код длини 7, например! 7D75a45

Comment: DBMS_RANDOM.STRING ?

Comment: да да даааааааааа

Comment: Akina можите помоч ?

Comment: Ну нет у меня Оракла. И никогда не было. Так что я могу только сказать, про что читать. Ну ещё могу сказать, куда пойти. Чтобы про это почитать. Вот сюда: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_random.htm#ARPLS67503

Comment: `select dbms_random.string('x',7) from dual;`?

Comment: Строки должны быть уникальными?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Триггер можно сделать так:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SCHEME."trigger1"
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON SCHEME.APP
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :NEW.PW := dbms_random.string('x', 7);
END;
/
```